# Beginners Question for Autodesk Maya - Where to ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about 3D modeling in Autodesk Maya. Which Stack Exchange site does this belong on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be on-topic on [Graphic Design.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), but I'd ask on their [meta-discussion site](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) first. According to [this meta discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/do-we-still-feel-like-3d-questions-are-out-of-scope-here) 3D questions should be on topic, but as it's an old discussion and they changed their mind once, it might have changed again so don't take this for granted.

There was a [3D Graphics Techniques and Software](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-techniques-and-software) proposal, which could likely be the best place to ask your question, but it was closed during its private beta.

Comment: It's worth noting that that SE site is now "Closed" as it didn't get enough attention during the beta.

Comment: @shadow Perhaps you could also update the answer regarding the 3D part. It apparently is on-topic now. https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/554/35770